# how to set a cookie after form submission in next.js

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js13

I am currently working on implementing a mechanism to set a cookie upon user submission of a form. Subsequently, upon receiving the server response, the cookie needs to be stored in accordance with this response. The challenge lies in the interplay between server and client components, leading to an error. Let's delineate the key points:
The form's signature necessitates the use of the client, given its reliance on the useState functionality.

Following user input submission, a fetch request is dispatched to the server. The subsequent steps involve creating a cookie based on the received response.

The crux of the issue arises during this process, where complications arise due to the integration of server and client components, resulting in an error.

the problems is here when i try to set a cookie in this logic using `cookies().set('name', 'lee')`.. it gives me an error of

```
ReactServerComponentsError:

You're importing a component that needs next/headers. That only works in a Server Component but one of its parents is marked with "use client", so it's a Client Component.
Learn more: https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials

   ,-[/workspaces/run_win_cap/app/(auth)/auth/signin/loginRequest.tsx:1:1]
 1 | 
 2 | import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
   : ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 3 | 
 4 | export async function sendLoginRequest(data:any){
 5 |     const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login_trianer/", {
   `----
```

here is my code :

**page.tsx**

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import SigninForm from "./signinForm";

const SignIn: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <>

      <div className="rounded-sm border border-stroke bg-white shadow-default dark:border-strokedark dark:bg-boxdark">
        <div className="flex flex-wrap items-center">
          <div className="hidden w-full xl:block xl:w-1/2">
            <div className="py-17.5 px-26 text-center">
              <Link className="mb-5.5 inline-block" href="/auth/signin">
                <Image
                  className="hidden dark:block"
                  src={"/images/logo/run_win_logo.png"}
                  alt="run win"
                  width={176}
                  height={32}
                />
                <Image
                  className="dark:hidden"
                  src={"/images/logo/run_win_logo.png"}
                  alt="Logo"
                  width={176}
                  height={32}
                />
              </Link>

              <p className="2xl:px-20">
                Welcome to the Run win captain dashboard
              </p>

            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="w-full border-stroke dark:border-strokedark xl:w-1/2 xl:border-l-2">
            <div className="w-full p-4 sm:p-12.5 xl:p-17.5">
              <span className="mb-1.5 block font-medium">Manage your trainereers</span>
              <h2 className="mb-9 text-2xl font-bold text-black dark:text-white sm:text-title-xl2">
                Sign In to Run Win
              </h2>
<SigninForm></SigninForm>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default SignIn;
```

**signinForm.tsx**

```
"use client"
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'
import { Metadata } from "next";
import { sendLoginRequest } from './loginRequest';

export default function SigninForm() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const handleSubmit = async (e: { preventDefault: () => void; }) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    setIsLoading(true)
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 3000))
    const data = {
      username, password
    }
    setIsLoading(false)
    const res = await sendLoginRequest(data)
      
  }

  return (
    <main>
      {isLoading ? (
        <div><h2>Cheking username and password ...!</h2></div>
      ) : (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} >
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label className="mb-2.5 block font-medium text-black dark:text-white">
              Username
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                type="text"
                className="w-full rounded-lg border border-stroke bg-transparent py-4 pl-6 pr-10 outline-none focus:border-primary focus-visible:shadow-none dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary"
                onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
              />
              <span className="absolute right-4 top-4">
                <svg
                  className="fill-current"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  viewBox="0 0 22 22"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <g opacity="0.5">
                    <path
                      d="M19.2516 3.30005H2.75156C1.58281 3.30005 0.585938 4.26255 0.585938 5.46567V16.6032C0.585938 17.7719 1.54844 18.7688 2.75156 18.7688H19.2516C20.4203 18.7688 21.4172 17.8063 21.4172 16.6032V5.4313C21.4172 4.26255 20.4203 3.30005 19.2516 3.30005ZM19.2516 4.84692C19.2859 4.84692 19.3203 4.84692 19.3547 4.84692L11.0016 10.2094L2.64844 4.84692C2.68281 4.84692 2.71719 4.84692 2.75156 4.84692H19.2516ZM19.2516 17.1532H2.75156C2.40781 17.1532 2.13281 16.8782 2.13281 16.5344V6.35942L10.1766 11.5157C10.4172 11.6875 10.6922 11.7563 10.9672 11.7563C11.2422 11.7563 11.5172 11.6875 11.7578 11.5157L19.8016 6.35942V16.5688C19.8703 16.9125 19.5953 17.1532 19.2516 17.1532Z"
                      fill=""
                    />
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-6">
            <label className="mb-2.5 block font-medium text-black dark:text-white">
              Password
            </label>
            <div className="relative">
              <input
                type="password"
                className="w-full rounded-lg border border-stroke bg-transparent py-4 pl-6 pr-10 outline-none focus:border-primary focus-visible:shadow-none dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:focus:border-primary"
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}

              />

              <span className="absolute right-4 top-4">
                <svg
                  className="fill-current"
                  width="22"
                  height="22"
                  viewBox="0 0 22 22"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                >
                  <g opacity="0.5">
                    <path
                      d="M16.1547 6.80626V5.91251C16.1547 3.16251 14.0922 0.825009 11.4797 0.618759C10.0359 0.481259 8.59219 0.996884 7.52656 1.95938C6.46094 2.92188 5.84219 4.29688 5.84219 5.70626V6.80626C3.84844 7.18438 2.33594 8.93751 2.33594 11.0688V17.2906C2.33594 19.5594 4.19219 21.3813 6.42656 21.3813H15.5016C17.7703 21.3813 19.6266 19.525 19.6266 17.2563V11C19.6609 8.93751 18.1484 7.21876 16.1547 6.80626ZM8.55781 3.09376C9.31406 2.40626 10.3109 2.06251 11.3422 2.16563C13.1641 2.33751 14.6078 3.98751 14.6078 5.91251V6.70313H7.38906V5.67188C7.38906 4.70938 7.80156 3.78126 8.55781 3.09376ZM18.1141 17.2906C18.1141 18.7 16.9453 19.8688 15.5359 19.8688H6.46094C5.05156 19.8688 3.91719 18.7344 3.91719 17.325V11.0688C3.91719 9.52189 5.15469 8.28438 6.70156 8.28438H15.2953C16.8422 8.28438 18.1141 9.52188 18.1141 11V17.2906Z"
                      fill=""
                    />
                    <path
                      d="M10.9977 11.8594C10.5852 11.8594 10.207 12.2031 10.207 12.65V16.2594C10.207 16.6719 10.5508 17.05 10.9977 17.05C11.4102 17.05 11.7883 16.7063 11.7883 16.2594V12.6156C11.7883 12.2031 11.4102 11.8594 10.9977 11.8594Z"
                      fill=""
                    />
                  </g>
                </svg>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-5">
            <input
              type="submit"
              value="Sign In"
              className="w-full cursor-pointer rounded-lg border border-primary bg-primary p-4 text-white transition hover:bg-opacity-90"
              disabled={isLoading}
            />
            {isLoading && "checking your data ..please wait"}
            {errorMsg === '' ? '' : (<div>
              <p>{errorMsg}</p>
            </div>)}
          </div>


        </form>

      )}
    </main>
  )
}
```

**loginRequest.tsx**

```
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

export async function sendLoginRequest(data:any){
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/login_trianer/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
  if (res.status === 401) {
    console.log("Login Failed")
  }
  if (res.status === 200) {
    const respBody = await res.json()
    cookies().set('name', 'lee')
  }
  return await res.json()

}
```